# Perl booleans, negation (and how to explain it)?

Tags: perl

I'm new here. After reading through how to ask and format, I hope this will be an OK question. I'm not very skilled in perl, but it is the programming language what I known most.

I trying apply Perl to real life but I didn't get an great understanding - especially not from my wife. I tell her that:

> if she didn't bring to me **3** beers in the evening, that means I got *zero (or nothing)* beers.

As you probably guessed, without much success. :(

Now factually. From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators):

> Unary "!" performs logical negation, that is, "not".

Languages, what have `boolean` types (what can have only two "values") is OK:

> if it is not the one value -> *must be* the another one.

so naturally:

```
!true  -> false
!false -> true
```

But perl doesn't have `boolean` variables - have only a `truth system`, whrere everything is not `0`, `'0'` `undef`, `''` is TRUE. Problem comes, when applying *logical negation* to an *not logical value* e.g. numbers.

E.g. If some number *IS NOT 3*, thats mean it *IS ZERO* or empty, instead of the *real life* meaning, where if something is NOT 3, mean it can be *anything but 3* (e.g. zero too).

So the next code:

```
use 5.014;
use Strictures;

my $not_3beers = !3;

say defined($not_3beers) ? "defined, value>$not_3beers<" : "undefined";
say $not_3beers ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";

my $not_4beers = !4;
printf qq{What is not 3 nor 4 mean: They're same value: %d!\n}, $not_3beers if( $not_3beers == $not_4beers );
say qq(What is not 3 nor 4 mean: @{[ $not_3beers ? "some bears" : "no bears" ]}!) if( $not_3beers eq $not_4beers );

say ' $not_3beers>',  $not_3beers, "<";
say '-$not_3beers>', -$not_3beers, "<";
say '+$not_3beers>', -$not_3beers, "<";
```

prints:

```
defined, value><
FALSE
What is not 3 nor 4 mean: They're same value: 0!
What is not 3 nor 4 mean: no bears!
 $not_3beers><
-$not_3beers>0<
+$not_3beers>0<
```

Moreover:

```
perl -E 'say !!4'
```

what is *not not 4* IS **1**, instead of 4!

The above statements with wife are "false" (mean 0) :), but **really trying teach my son** Perl and he, after a while, asked my wife: *why, if something is not 3 mean it is 0 ?* .

So the questions are:

- how to explain this to my son
- why perl has this design, so why `!0` is everytime 1
- Is here something "behind" what requires than `!0` is not any *random number*, but 0.
- as I already said, I don't know well other languages - in every language is `!3 == 0`?

Comment: I feel like there is some profound argument trying to be made here I just fail to see what it is.

Comment: going to try the perl's logic with my wife & beers :)

Comment: I've not had not three beers. Does that mean I've had four beers?

Comment: Probably your wife using overloaded `!` operator. :) Check the `overload::Overloaded $beer`.

Comment: The `!` operator applies to boolean values.  The expression `!3` is a shorthand for `!(3 != 0)`, the parenthesized expression representing the implicit boolean value that is being negated. Because `(3 != 0)` is true or 1, its negation is 0 or false. That's why `!3 == !4`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are focussing to much on negation and too little on what Perl booleans mean.

#### Historical/Implementation Perspective

What is truth? The detection of a higher voltage that x Volts.

On a higher abstraction level: If this bit here is set.

The abstraction of a sequence of bits can be considered an integer. Is this integer false? Yes, if no bit is set, i.e. the integer is zero.

A hardware-oriented language will likely use this definition of truth, e.g. C, and all C descendants incl Perl.

The negation of `0` could be bitwise negation—all bits are flipped to `1`—, or we just set the last bit to `1`. The results would usually be decoded as integers `-1` and `1` respectively, but the latter is more energy efficient.

#### Pragmatic Perspective

It is *convenient* to think of all numbers but zero as *true* when we deal with counts:

```
my $wordcount = ...;

if ($wordcount) {
  say "We found $wordcount words";
} else {
  say "There were no words";
}
```

or

```
say "The array is empty" unless @array;  # notice scalar context
```

A pragmatic language like Perl will likely consider zero to be false.

#### Mathematical Perspective

There is no reason for any number to be false, every number is a well-defined entity. Truth or falseness emerges solely through predicates, expressions which can be true or false. Only this truth value can be negated. E.g.

```
¬(x ≤ y) where x = 2, y = 3
```

is false. Many languages which have a strong foundation in maths won't consider anything false but a special false value. In Lisps, `'()` or `nil` is usually false, but `0` will usually be true. That is, a value is only true if it is not nil!

In such mathematical languages, `!3 == 0` is likely a type error.

#### Re: Beers

Beers are good. Any number of beers are good, as long as you have one:

```
my $beers = ...;

if (not $beers) {
  say "Another one!";
} else {
  say "Aaah, this is good.";
}
```

Boolification of a beer-counting variable just tells us if you have any beers. Consider `!!` to be a boolification operator:

```
my $enough_beer = !! $beers;
```

The boolification doesn't concern itself with the exact amount. But maybe any number ≥ 3 is good. Then:

```
my $enough_beer = ($beers >= 3);
```

The negation is not enough beer:

```
my $not_enough_beer = not($beers >= 3);
```

or

```
my $not_enough_beer = not $beers;

fetch_beer() if $not_enough_beer;
```

#### Sets

A Perl scalar does not symbolize a whole universe of things. Especially, `not 3` is not the set of all entities that are not three. Is the expression `3` a truthy value? Yes. Therefore, `not 3` is a falsey value.

The suggested behaviour of `4 == not 3` to be true is likely undesirable: `4` and “all things that are not three” are not *equal*, the four is just one of many things that are not three. We should write it correctly:

```
4 != 3    # four is not equal to three
```

or

```
not( 4 == 3 )   # the same
```

It might help to think of `!` and `not` as *logical-negation-of*, but not as *except*.

#### How to teach

It might be worth introducing mathematical predicates: expressions which can be true or false. If we only ever “create” truthness by explicit tests, e.g. `length($str) > 0`, then your issues don't arise. We can name the results: `my $predicate = (1 < 2)`, but we can decide to never print them out, instead: `print $predicate ? "True" : "False"`. This sidesteps the problem of considering special representations of *true* or *false*.

Considering values to be true/false directly would then only be a shortcut, e.g. `foo if $x` can considered to be a shortcut for

```
foo if defined $x and length($x) > 0 and $x != 0;
```

Perl is all about shortcuts.

Teaching these shortcuts, and the various contexts of perl and where they turn up (numeric/string/boolean operators) could be helpful.

- List Context

  - Even-sized List Context
- Scalar Context

  - Numeric Context
  - String Context
  - Boolean Context
- Void Context

Answer (score 8):

> - *as I already said, I don't know well other languages - in every language is !3 == 0?*

- Yes. In C (and thus C++), it's the same.

  ```
  void main() {
      int i = 3;
      int n = !i;
      int nn = !n;
      printf("!3=%i ; !!3=%i\n", n, nn);
  }
  ```

  Prints (see http://codepad.org/vOkOWcbU )

  ```
  !3=0 ; !!3=1
  ```

---

> - *how to explain this to my son*

- Very simple. `!3` means "opposite of **some** non-false value, which is of course false". This is called "context" - in a Boolean context imposed by negation operator, "3" is NOT a number, it's a statement of true/false.

  The result is also not a "zero" but merely something that's convenient Perl representation of false - which turns into a zero if used in a numeric context (but an empty string if used in a string context -  see the difference between `0 + !3` and `!3 . "a"`)

  > The Boolean context is just a special kind of scalar context where no conversion to a string or a number is ever performed. ([`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html))

---

> - *why perl has this design, so why !0 is everytime 1*

- See above. Among other likely reasons (though I don't know if that was Larry's main reason), C has the same logic and Perl took a lot of its syntax and ideas from C.

  For a VERY good underlying technical detail, see the answers here: " [What do Perl functions that return Boolean actually return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520266/what-do-perl-functions-that-return-boolean-actually-return) " and here: " [Why does Perl use the empty string to represent the boolean false value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914129/why-does-perl-use-the-empty-string-to-represent-the-boolean-false-value/3914490#3914490) "

---

> - *Is here something "behind" what requires than !0 is not any random number, but 0.*

- Nothing aside from simplicity of implementation. It's easier to produce a "1" than a random number.
- if you're asking a **different** question of "why is it 1 instead of the original # that was negated to get 0", the answer to that is simple - by the time Perl interpreter gets to negate that zero, it no longer knows/remembers that zero was a result of "!3" as opposed to some other expression that resulted in a value of zero/false.

Comment: +!0 :) That's what i called _THE answer_ for an "not easy" question. ;) Nice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test that a number is not 3, then use this:

```
my_variable != 3;
```

Using the syntax `!3`, since `!` is a boolean operator, first converts `3` into a boolean (even though `perl` may not have an official boolean type, it still works this way), which, since it is non-zero, means it gets converted to the equivalent of `true`. Then, `!true` yields `false`, which, when converted back to an integer context, gives `0`. Continuing with that logic shows how `!!3` converts `3` to `true`, which then is inverted to `false`, inverted again back to `true`, and if this value is used in an integer context, gets converted to `1`. This is true of most modern programming languages (although maybe not some of the more logic-centered ones), although the exact syntax may vary some depending on the language...

Answer (score 0):

Logically negating a false value requires *some* value be chosen to represent the resulting true value. "1" is as good a choice as any. I would say it is not important which value is returned (or conversely, it is important that you not rely on any particular true value being returned).