# Perl not of a string equals to?

Tags: perl

```
my $pass = !$message;
```

I came across this perl code where $message is a string and $pass is suppose to be a boolean value. that will be checked as

```
ok ($pass, $test)
```

I am confused what is a not (!) of $message?
How does this tranlate to a boolean value?

empty string is False and nonempty string is True?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134962/why-does-1-give-me-nothing-in-perl

Comment: In addition to the answers you can search for "boolean context". `perldoc perldata` has some info about it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!` is the unary logical negation operator. False strings are `""` and `"0"`. If such a string is negated logically, this evaluates to `1`. All other strings are true-ish. The negation of these is `""` (the empty string) or numerically `0`.

Other false values are `undef` and the number `0`.

Therefore, the `ok ($pass, $test)` will pass if `$message` is undefined, the empty string, or zero.

Comment: this might be irrelevant but then if i do $pass = $message then does $pass save the boolean value of $message or the actual string? logically speaking, i am guessing it would just save the text of $message and when ok ($pass, $test) is executed, $pass would be treated as boolean ie true if not empty.

Comment: @ealeon Your understanding is correct. The assignment operator `=` copies the value (of the string). If you want to explicitly bool-ify any value, use double negation: `my $bool = !! $foo`.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly right. In perl, the following items are 'false':

```
0
''
'0'
undef
```

Anything else is true. So, if `$message` is not either empty, undefined, or `'0'`, then `$message` is true, and `!$message` is false.