# Perl : why I can't print !$num? when num is 1, it cannot print 0

Tags: perl

```
print !$num;
```

When $num is 1, I expect to see 0.  But, nothing is printed.    why is it?   Thank you for any comment.

Here are some tests I tried.  It is consistent with my problem.

```
print 1;     # 1
print 0;     # 0
print !1;    # (nothing)
print !0;    # 1
print !1 == 0;  # 1
```

Michael

Answer (score 5):

The “false” boolean in Perl is special value that when evaluated as a string is treated as `""`, but in a numerical context, it is treated as `0`.

That is why when printing the negated true value, you're seeing the empty string:

```
$ perl -MData::Dump -e 'dd !1'
""
```

To see the value `0`, you must use it in a numerical context.  You can do this by simply adding 0 to the value:

```
$ perl -MData::Dump -e 'dd 0 + !1'
0
```

For more information on booleans, check [perldata - Scalar Values](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).

Comment: Re "The default “false” boolean in Perl is the empty string `''`". Not it's not. It's a dual var that contains `0` and the empty string. `perl -wE'say 0+!1; say 0+""'` only warns for the latter statement.

Comment: Yes, I know that's technically true.  However, I'm not sure how to frame that in beginner's language.  I'll consider it and come back, or feel free to give me a hand.

Comment: I think the bottom [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1140031/176646) to the dupe target explains it well, although it's a bit long. Especially the part at the end: "in summary, you aren't getting nothing, you aren't getting an empty string, and you aren't getting zero. You are getting a variable that is both an empty string and 0 at the same time."

Comment: "A value that's an empty string when treated as a string and zero when treated as a number"

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood),

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.
>   Negation of a true value by ! or not returns a special false value.
>   When evaluated as a string it is treated as "" , but as a number, it
>   is treated as 0. Most Perl operators that return true or false behave
>   this way.

`print` is evaluating `!1` as a string, so it is being treated as a `""`.

---

If you evaluate `!1` in a numeric context, it will be treated as a `0`.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e'print Dumper !1+!1'
$VAR1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, there's a variety of values that are `true` and a variety of values that are `false`. So `not true` is valid in a boolean context, but ambiguous when you `print` it.