# Why false value outputs as empty string?

Tags: perl, boolean, equality-operator

```
print "Result: " . (0 == 1); # Result:
print "Result: " . (1 == 1); # Result: 1
```

Why does perl output an empty string for a false value and not `0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does !1 give me nothing in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134962/why-does-1-give-me-nothing-in-perl) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914129/why-does-perl-use-the-empty-string-to-represent-the-boolean-false-value?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Because in Perl, the false value returned by many operators and builtins is a special value that is 0 in a numeric context and '' in a string context.